# Is it possible to run tasks in Ruby simultaneously during one Rails call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I want to make a call to a Rails server, which then makes, say, 10 calls to external APIs, one at a time, and then returns the results once all the work is done.

So if x is the time it takes for one of those API calls to happen, then the request takes 10x.

But I am wondering if there is any threading possibility to make all the calls at once and then have them occur simultaneously so the whole request is only about as long as the slowest external API call.

I am using Rails and Heroku and am wondering about any possible solutions for this.

Comment: You need a quick a dirty solution, or a new approach ? ( I will detail in the answer)

Comment: I can suggest you using frameworks like async_sinatra https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra, it isn't a fix for your current issue (that is why I haven't posted an answer) but an whole new approach similar to node.js, it would make easier this kind of things

Comment: @spitfire, did my answer answer your question?

Comment: Yes sorry, I fell ill and was away from work stuff. I marked it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **make** concurrent requests, consider checking out https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus. According to their Readme: "Typhoeus runs HTTP requests in parallel while cleanly encapsulating handling logic."

To **process** concurrent requests, consider using a multi-threaded web server like Puma, or a multi-process web server like Unicorn.

Here is an article written by Heroku on deploying Rails applications to Puma:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server

Here is another article written by Heroku on deploying Rails applications to Unicorn: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn

Comment: +1 Typhoeus and it's accompanying Hydra, are a very good, well tested, solution for doing this.